# Characterizing categories of algebras of monads as locally presentable categories

Tags: category-theory, monads, locally-presentable-categories

In *Accessible Categories: The Foundations of Categorical Model Theory* (Makkai, Paré), it is said (Introduction, p. 3):

> One sign of the “rightness” of the notion [of locally presentable category] is that it is easy to characterize the categories of algebras of equational theories, the ones that the theory of monads is for, as locally presentable categories satisfying a simple additional property.

What is this additional property that Makkai and Paré are talking about?

Comment: The claim is a bit strange. Not every monad on $\textbf{Set}$ is accessible, so not every category of algebras is locally presentable either. If we restrict to accessible monads then perhaps the additional property being alluded to is the existence of a strong generator whose representable preserves $\kappa$-sifted colimits for some $\kappa$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, this is helpful. Maybe it was that. It applies also to any cocomplete category (replacing strong separator by extremal) and the accessibility is here to give the bound $κ$ on the arity of the operations. Maybe this is what they were pointing out: if a category of algebras for a monad on sets is locally presentable, then the accessibility gives a bound on the cardinality of the operations. But maybe they had a more “intrinsinc” characterization without referring to the forgetful functor... ?